# Express/NodeJS app does not behave the same when run locally vs on Amazon AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a relatively simple Express/NodeJS app to Amazon AWS elastic beanstalk.  When I run the app locally from my laptop (OSX 10.10.5) everything runs well and all pages load successfully.  However when the app is deployed to Amazon AWS EB, the app is only able to display two of the pages (the root and survey page) and attempting to access any of the other pages produces the error `Cannot GET /<url>`.

My server.js file appears as follows:

```
//Get modules.
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.locals.theme = process.env.THEME;

var config = fs.readFileSync('./app_config.json', 'utf8');
config = JSON.parse(config);
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: config.AWS_REGION});

//GET home page.
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { appTitle: 'O2X Human Performance', 'theme': 'default'});
});

//GET survey page.
app.get('/survey', function(req, res){
  res.render('survey', { appTitle: 'Survey', 'theme': 'default'});
});

app.get('/view-report/:id', function(req, res){
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log('retrieving report:', id);
  res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname+'/reports/'+id+'.html'));
});

app.get('/report/:id', function(req, res){
  var id = req.params.id;
  res.render('report', {'id': id});
});

app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
//some DB stuff that's not relevant
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
  console.log('Woo hoo');
});
```

My folder containing everything is setup as follows:

```
myapp
|- app_config.json
|- iam_policy.json
|- package.json
|- public
   |- static
      |- bootstrap
      |- images
      |- jQuery
|- routes
   |- index.js
   |- login.js
|- server.js
|- views
   |- index.jade
   |- layout.jade
   |- report.jade
   |- survey.jade
```

Any help with identifying what might be causing the errors just when it is deployed to Amazon AWS EB would be appreciated.